# iDRAC 6 Power Monitoring Not displaying

Tags: monitoring, dell, electrical-power, drac

I recently bought a Dell R210ii with a iDRAC6 Enterprise card installed.

Everything seems to be fine except there is no mention of power monitoring on the iDRAC website, only voltage status. According to the user guide this server should have power monitoring functionality. iDRAC has been updated to latest version.

Running CLI commands for power monitoring also gives no meaningful data, output below.

```
admin-> racadm getconfig -g cfgServerPower

# cfgServerPowerStatus=1
# cfgServerPowerAllocation=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerActualPowerConsumption=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerMinPowerCapacity=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerMaxPowerCapacity=180 AC W | 616 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPeakPowerConsumption=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPeakPowerConsumptionTimestamp=Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
# cfgServerPowerConsumptionClear=******** (Write-Only)
cfgServerPowerCapWatts=180 AC W
cfgServerPowerCapBtuhr=614 btu/hr
cfgServerPowerCapPercent=100
cfgServerPowerCapEnable=0
# cfgServerPowerLastMinAvg=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPowerLastHourAvg=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPowerLastDayAvg=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPowerLastWeekAvg=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPowerLastHourMinPower=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPowerLastHourMinTime=Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
# cfgServerPowerLastHourMaxPower=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPowerLastHourMaxTime=Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
# cfgServerPowerLastDayMinPower=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPowerLastDayMinTime=Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
# cfgServerPowerLastDayMaxPower=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPowerLastDayMaxTime=Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
# cfgServerPowerLastWeekMinPower=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPowerLastWeekMinTime=Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
# cfgServerPowerLastWeekMaxPower=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPowerLastWeekMaxTime=Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
# cfgServerPowerInstHeadroom=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerPowerPeakHeadroom=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerActualAmperageConsumption=0.0 Amps
# cfgServerPeakAmperage=0.0 Amps
# cfgServerPeakAmperageTimeStamp=Sun Jan 00 00:00:00 1900
# cfgServerCumulativePowerConsumption=0 AC W | 0 Btu/hr
# cfgServerCumulativePowerConsumptionTimeStamp=Sun Jan 00 00:00:00 1900
# cfgServerCumulativePowerClear=******** (Write-Only)
# cfgServerPeakPowerClear=******** (Write-Only)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked on two Dell (R610) and I can see more information. Your server PS model seem to allow less monitoring option.

Please check in the Dell OpenManage too. You can see power management informaton from there.

On my side I can see the current amp per PS, the watt, btu/hr, total energy consumed and some reading for the systemboard power current power consummation. (Directly in the Power Management from the openmanage or the drac's console)

Comment: I have a R410 that is working fine, its just this R210ii isn't displaying power info, and according to all the documentation it should support full power info and graphing. Ill try OpenManage but I haven't currently got any windows instances running on it.

Comment: @dewso I would check with the reseller then if the openmanage show nothing more. The reseller can check with dell and offer you something in case it's a sale error. The term power management is vague. I just hope for you they will not tell that you can see the W and AC, so it's ok for them.